# Jenkins react on git push? Polling?

Tags: git, jenkins, debian, bitbucket

I have an local Jenkins server under localhost:8080 running, which is running in a Virtual Machine on debian7.

Host System is Windows8.

Now I want that every time I Push something from My hostsystem to mit bitbucket git repository the local jenkins server in the vm should pull the new commit and then starting a sonar Check on it.

**How do I have to configurate jenkins that he pull the new commit automatically??**

Sonar Qube is installed and running.
Sonar Runner is also installed
Git also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Git post commit hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook)

Comment: thanks but whats not mentioned how to config the hook for a local server? which is not reachable from outside? ..

Comment: What I want is that the jenkins does a polling and checks (for example) every 5 minutes if the repo has changed ... and if thats true the build should start

Comment: Where do I have to put the hook?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository on Host or on VM

Comment: Avoid poling and use the hooks instead. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250478/734790) about using the [Bitbucket plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Does your Jenkins job working fine (as expected) when started manually ?
2 Does your Git commands (via commandline are working fine (as expected) in a shell on your debian ?
3 If it is the case .. you can then concentrate your study on to the configuration of Git In Jenkins.
4 Have a pass on the gloal Jenkins Configuration, (polling definition, git configuration)

5 If nothing better .. please, send more accurate information to help people pushing the finger on the the right issue.

thanks.

Comment: 1) yes job works fine manualle 2) yes I can use git normally from shell 4) what do you mean?

Comment: In Jenkins you configure things globally (for all jobs) and things for each job when you create one.

Comment: If I understand clearly you just want to poll the git repository and start if changes occure. In this case just configure the SCM Trigger Configuration with something like H 0 * * 0-5.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I've doing now, because the hook dosn't work