# Jenkins web-hook trigger for commits against open PR

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-api, git-webhooks

I already integrated my Bitbucket server with Jenkins server and it works fine. I want to configure this integration (Jenkins servers <-----------> Bitbucket server in a way that a developer commit for a ***open pull request***, webhook should trigger the corresponding Jenkins job.

References:

(1) https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-trigger-a-webhook-when-a-commit-is-pushed-to-an-open-pull/qaq-p/1029556

(2) https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Atlassian-supported-Jenkins-integration-for-Bitbucket-Server/ba-p/1148326

[image]

Comment: Our QA team has done it at Swiggy.So it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231064/how-do-i-get-jenkins-to-build-on-push-to-a-bitbucket-git-repository

Comment: Hi @RajanPrasad sorry I could not find it, just to explain again, we could able to create webhook for the push commit, But what we want is to create webhook triggers ONLY against open pull requests pushes/commits

Answer (score 0):

From Bitbucket version 7.0, this is available as `a new webhook - 'Source branch updated'.` Check out the ticket [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10279) for more info.

Comment: Only works for BitBucket *Server* though. If you're on Cloud, then almost 2 years later we still don't have it 